# Plugin start level via properties file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How we can set plug-in Start Level via some properties file? How stable this start level is? Would it be guaranteed to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out. We can set it in config.ini file present in configuration folder of eclipse installation. There we need to add/change following line:

```
 osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the stat level using product file, go to  configuration tab under product file  and add the set the plugin startup level.
which internally overwrite config.ini file present in configuration folder

---

" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" />
       ...
       ...